# React Native IDE that allows debugging/breakpoints

Tags: debugging, react-native, ide

What IDE would you recommend to use with React Native that provides simple to use debugging/tracing code using break points?

I have tried VS Code and while I like it, debugging seem to be not working

I cannot use WebStorm as it is not free

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is not allowed on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging remotely with chrome works pretty swimmingly. Lets you step through functions line by line.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating bit, never did that.  How do I debug RN app in Chrome?

Comment: Same way you would do it it on the web. Try console.log -ing and it will show up in Chrome's inspect element => console. Just make sure to press cmd + D in simulator to enable debugging